# onclick & несколько элементов

Tags: javascript, click

Всем привет.

суть проблемы - есть много элементов с разметкой как ниже. На них навешиваются функции onclick.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var goods = document.querySelectorAll('div.good');

  for (var z = 0; z < goods.length; z++) {
    goods[z].onclick = function() {
      var text = this.querySelector('.details p').innerHTML;
      var img = this.querySelector('img').getAttribute('src');
      alert(img + ' ' + text);
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="good">
  <img src="/assets/img/good4.png">
  <div class="details">
    <div><span class="icon goods beef blue"></span>
    </div>
    <p>Курица по-тайски</p>
    <span class="price">299</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="good">
  <img src="/assets/img/good2.png">
  <div class="details">
    <div><span class="icon goods beef blue"></span>
    </div>
    <p>Говядина томленая</p>
    <span class="price">228</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

В итоге элемент по которому кликаем не соответствует тому, что получаем через `this` в функции. Воспроизвести не смогу, поэтому могу только преддложить посмотреть в живую - music.redeye.pro
(Речь идёт о клике на товары).
Спасибо.

Характерно, что проявляется это для нижних рядов, а в this прилетают верхние над ними

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элементы

`<img class="under" src="/assets/img/circle.png">`

в первом ряду накрывают все, что ниже. Click-и попадают в них.

Comment: боже, огромное Вам спасибо.))

Answer (score 1):

Получается что блок мешает кликать по элкментам,
скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал скрыть его, тогда все ок!

Comment: вы абсолютно правы, только чуть-чуть опоздали. Спасибо)